# Select sum of groupped values and values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of payments with dates and comments:

```
id | summ | date | comment
```

I want to select list of values ordered by date and sum of them grouped by date.
I know how to get sum of values grouped by date

```
SELECT date, sum(summ) GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

but i also want to select values.

for example if my table looks like

```
1 | 1200 | 24.05.2015 | apple
2 | 250  | 24.05.2015 | banana
3 | 700  | 27.05.2015 | peach
4 | 1350 | 27.05.2015 | lemon
3 | 120  | 29.05.2015 | grape
4 | 7350 | 30.05.2015 | grape and two apples
```

I want to receive

```
24.05.2015 | 1450 | apple 1200, banana 250
27.05.2015 | 2150 | peach 700, lemon 1350
29.05.2015 | 120  | grape 120
30.05.2015 | 7350 | grape and two apples 7350
```

Comment: I think what you want is reasonably clear, but it might help you to be more explicit about what you want in the last column. I am not familiar with any SQL syntax that offers this, but maybe someone else is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, sum(summ), group_concat(concat(comment, ' ', summ))
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date
```